# How to check if a repository has files for which a clean/smudge filter is set up that haven’t been processed?

Tags: git, git-lfs

I’ve introduced `git-lfs` on a project fairly recently, and we’ve been hitting some PEBKACs where builds would produce bad output that manifests in non-obvious ways. The culprit was assets that are stored in Git-LFS - the build was grabbing the pointer files.

Can I detect that I have such files in the repository - because git-lfs hasn’t been installed, or because fetching the files failed - so I can blow up the build?

---

(For some additional context: the assets in question are PouchDB / Leveldown database files. The app needs a bunch of read-only data, and there’s enough of it that initializing the indexes if it’s loaded from JSON on first start is unacceptably slow, so we just want to ship the full pre-built DB. This is about 300MB data that needs updating like once or twice a year, so it’d soon baloon a clone to over a GB of mostly useless binaries, so I’m shoving it into LFS. Vexingly, since this a first-start optimization, the bug won’t manifest during regular development - if there’s any data in the app’s storage dir it’ll use that; eventually I’ll get around to setting up appropriate E2E testing of builds and add some sort of checksum to avoid bootstrapping with corrupted data, but for now I’d like something quick and dirty I can fail a build on immediately.)